# Yii2. Date validation rule wrong format

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I have such validation rule

```
['birthdate', 'date', 'format' => 'Y-m-d'],
```

and passing such value `2002-03-11`, but recive validation error `The format of Birthdate is invalid.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed `intl` extenstion. It has fixed an issue.

Comment: @ShaigKhaligli actually, not. Inside the Yii2 Date core validator was if this extension installed and else with some code and this part gave an error.